# BroadcastReceiver/Widget custom intent filter firing on its own

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to create a home screen widget and periodically update it by broadcasting, from a service**(Service not yet implemented)**, the 4 action strings that are shown below.

```
public final static String BATTERY_UPDATE = "com.app.MyApp.action.BATTERY_UPDATE";
public final static String CPU_UPDATE = "com.app.MyApp.action.CPU_UPDATE";
public final static String SYSTEM_UPDATE = "com.app.MyApp.action.SYSTEM_UPDATE";
public final static String RAM_UPDATE = "com.app.MyApp.action.RAM_UPDATE";
```

inside the widget class, i override the on receive method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    switch(intent.getAction()){

        case BATTERY_UPDATE:
            Log.i("Widget", "Battery Update");
            break;

        case CPU_UPDATE:
            Log.i("Widget", "CPU Update");
            break;

        case RAM_UPDATE:
            Log.i("Widget", "RAM Update");
            break;

        case SYSTEM_UPDATE:
            Log.i("Widget", "System Update");
            break;

        case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
            Log.i("Widget", "Screen Off");
            break;
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

so far so good, however, as soon as i add the intent filter to the widget in the onUpdate method, i suddenly start to receiver broadcasts every 5 seconds or so with the action strings that i specified above, below is the on receive method

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.i("Widget", "onUpdate");

    Context c = context.getApplicationContext();

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter();
    filter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter1.addAction(CPU_UPDATE);
    filter1.addAction(BATTERY_UPDATE);
    filter1.addAction(SYSTEM_UPDATE);
    filter1.addAction(RAM_UPDATE);
    c.registerReceiver(this, filter1);

}
```

The first action added (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) is working fine and i only receive a broadcast when the screen turns off, but the other 4 just keeps firing, this also happens if i specify those 4 actions in the manifest. Can someone please explain to me what is going on here, how am i receiving a broadcast with an action string that **I** defined, when i never sent a broadcast in the first place?

**EDIT:** So i changed the compiler compliance level to 1.6, and i'm still receiving the broadcasts, here is the edited code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//  switch(intent.getAction()){
//  
//      case BATTERY_UPDATE:
//          Log.i("Widget", "Battery Update");
//          break;
//          
//      case CPU_UPDATE:
//          Log.i("Widget", "CPU Update");
//          break;
//          
//      case RAM_UPDATE:
//          Log.i("Widget", "RAM Update");
//          break;
//          
//      case SYSTEM_UPDATE:
//          Log.i("Widget", "System Update");
//          break;
//
//      case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
//          Log.i("Widget", "Screen Off");
//          break;
//  }
    Log.i("Widget", intent.getAction());
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Comment: Where in your code to you actually send intents with these custom actions?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer That's the thing, i never broadcast any of them but somehow i'm receiving broadcasts, that is the problem that i was having, but rebooting the phone seem to get rid of that problem, i'm guessing that it might have something to do with the way android creates widgets and even after installing the new app with eclipse, the old widgets were probably still in memory and rebooting the phone cleared it, that's the best i could come up with :-\

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I'm thinking that in an older version of the app i was broadcasting those actions, then when i re-installed the app with eclipse, the old app stayed in memory

Comment: It's not likely in either case.  Widgets or the Widget holder won't generate broadcasts for you - it's up to your code to broadcast your own custom `Intent`.  Similarly, when you re-install an application (due to an update) any existing process for that app is killed before the new APK is installed.  Are your custom broadcasts being sent as "sticky"?  If so, that may explain what you are seeing, particularly because you are re-registering for the broadcast each time `onUpdate()` is called.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Hmmmm, i see, no the broadcast are not being sent as sticky either, that is really weird because there is not a single piece of code in my application where i call sendBroadcast(), nowhere, what you see in the code i posted is all there is, as soon as i call c.registerReceiver(this, filter1) in the onUpdate method, that's when the craziness starts

Comment: @LarrySchiefer The same thing was also happening when i registered the actions in the manifest

Comment: You mentioned that you were sending your custom broadcasts in a service.  Has that service been completely removed or modified such that it doesn't send the broadcasts any longer?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I should edit my question, because i never actually implemented anything in the service because i was facing this problem, the service basically was a shell

Comment: Something still isn't adding up: the system doesn't spontaneously start broadcasting intents just based on an `IntentFilter`.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I know right, i almost went mad yesterday, thankfully it's working now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at your `switch` statement. You can't do switch on Strings. `byte`, `char`, `int`, `short` are the only things you can switch on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, while it is correct that you cannot switch on strings in java versions 1.6 and below, i have set the compiler compliance level to version 1.7 so in my case the switch statement is valid

Comment: This is android its supposed to be lightweight and fast.  Switching on a string would force java to interate over every byte in the string needless wasted cpu.  Maybe if you recompiled android over 1.6 this would work.

Comment: The switch statement is working, the problem is that i am receiving broadcasts that i should not be receiving, even when debugging i can clearly see that the action string contained in the intent is one of the four action string that i defined

Comment: Ok, i changed the compliance level to 1.6 and i'm still getting the broadcasts, i am completely lost with this

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e just rebooted my phones and all the problems seems to be fixed now